# DialogFragment shows only once -

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-dialogfragment

So i'm having one dialog that i'm trying to show from an Activity 
this activity has a navigation graph (JETPACK)

for now i can show this popup only once if i'm in my Activity 
then if i close the activity and come back again to it, it's won't show the Dialog because the state of the activity is already saved. and i'm using `commitAllowingStateLoss` to commit this dialog fragment if i use commit it's crashing. i searched everywhere in stackoverflow couldn't find a single solution for this problem.

code of how im showing the fragment:

```
 public void show(Context context) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_DIALOG);
    if (prev != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.add(this, TAG_DIALOG);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show how you open the fragment.

Do you save anything when the activity closes? I can only imagine problems with saving the actual fragment instance, but it's all guess work without seeing any code.

Comment: Hi i just added the code to the issue , please refresh to see it.

Comment: Can't really see anything that might capture variables when leaving the scope. I could imagine something happening with the fragment possibly removing itself from the manager, trying to kill itself. What's the exception say? Also: It feels strange to have the fragment 'show' itself, although I haven't used android professionally, so I'm not sure that's just the amateur in me speaking.

Comment: thanks sandy i think we should wait for experts to answer this. thank you.